# Parametrized Table Name in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to generate documentation for my BigQuery projects, I have several projects in Google Cloud, and each project contains several BigQuery Datasets. I am trying to get metadata by running

```
SELECT * FROM `<project>.<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`;
SELECT * FROM `<project>.<dataset>.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`;
```

The issue is as I mentioned before, I have several projects and datasets. It's almost impossible to run this manually for each dataset and project. I took a look at BigQuery scripting (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting#syntax_2) but could not find a way to make the table name a variable.

Any ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: BigQuery suppots parameterised queries where project, dataset and table can be one of the query parameters. _"but could not find a way to make the table name a variable"_ - this [project](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery) gets such information from the environment [variables](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/blob/master/server/.env), stores it in a Javascript/TypeScript variable and supplies it as a parameter of the query.

Comment: What exactly do you need? You need only the list if columns and table for all your projects and datasets?

Comment: I finally implemented it via a Python script, looping through a list of projects and calling the INFORMATION_SCHEMA query for each dataset. Could not find a way to do it directly with SQL or a SQL script in the BigQuery console.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: yes via python script.. not what I hoped for but it works.